# Template class Y in namespace X with class X can't compile in VS2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, templates

When I have a class with the same name as the namespace it is contained in (`A::A`) and then define a templated class in the same namespace the compilation fails if and only if I define the functions of the templated class outside of the namespace using the scope resolution operator (`A::B<type>::...`). This is in Visual studio 2010. When I compile the code at http://ideone.com/ it works in both cases below.

Can anyone explain why this might happen?

```
namespace A
{
    template<typename type>
    class B
    {
    public:
        B();
    };

    class A
    {
    };  
}

/* 1. Doing this works
namespace A
{
    template<typename type>
    B<type>::B()
    {
    }
}
*/

/* 2. error C2039: 'B' : is not a member of 'A::A'
template<typename type>
A::B<type>::B()
{
}
*/

int main()
{
    A::B<int> test;
}
```

Comment: #2 works with clang 3.3 on my Mac, fyi. If you happened to have a VS2012 or later handy i'm curious to know if this was addressed post-Novemeber 2012 CTP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a compiler bug. If you will define the constructor the following way

```
template<typename type>
::A::B<type>::B()
{
}
```

when MS VC++ will compile the code without errors.

Answer (score 0):

Class and namespace names may clash in [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b)! Don't use classnames named the same as their containing namespace.
I have no standard cite about how this should behave at hand actually, but experienced this a number of times. It seems to be compiler implementation dependent behavior.

Comment: @WhozCraig Also does for gcc 4.3.2, but certainly remember having the same error ...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a bug. You can make Visual C++ to compile the code 2 in the following manner:

```
template<typename type>
::A::B<type>::B()
{
}
```